# Не отображается кириллица при запуске через exec

Tags: php, exec

Доброго времени суток. Столкнулся с такой проблемой, если jar(spigot) приложение запускать через ssh, то с кириллицей все нормально, но вот если запускать ее через php exec, то вместо кириллицы восклицательные знаки. Все костыли перепробовал, не выходит. Как это можно исправить?
Пробовал добавить к строке запуска -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8, тогда вообще кракозябры.

Сама строка запуска:

```
exec("cd /путь; sudo ./start.sh");
```

файл start.sh:

```
screen -S server -d -m java -Xincgc -server -Xmx4G -Xms4G -jar Spigot.jar
```

OC: Debian php: 5.6

Comment: Попробуйте использовать кодировку, которая поддерживает кириллицу. `utf-8`, насколько я знаю, с кириллицей не дружит. Может вам подойдет `windows-1251`

Comment: @Klimenkomud, к сожалению выдает Ìàêñèìóì ïàìÿòè

Comment: @Klimenkomud Возможно проблема в самом php файле. В какой кодировке он сохранен?

Comment: @GardenMan, utf-8 без bom

Comment: @TheStarLord Тогда попробуйте добавить `AddDefaultCharset UTF-8` в .htaccess.

Comment: @GardenMan, а это тут причем? htaccess не должен влиять на файл, а кодировка в самом приложении. то есть даже в логах ??? вместо кириллицы. upd: не работает

Comment: @TheStarLord У меня когда-то был похожий случай. Кодировка файла тоже был UTF-8 без Bom. Тогда я лечил его добавив AddDefaultCharset UTF-8 в .htaccess.

Comment: ассоциация: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13969829/1216425 не пойдет?

Comment: @teran, все работает! спасибо!

Comment: @TheStarLord Проблема в Locale было что-ли?

Comment: @teran, переводи ответ.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Проблему решили вот такие параметры:

```
$locale='ru_RU.UTF-8';
setlocale(LC_ALL,$locale);
putenv('LC_ALL='.$locale);
```

Всем спасибо! Проблема решена.