# Выводит крякозябры при считывании букв русского алфавита

Tags: java, консоль

Считываю файл, с латинскими буквами всё нормально, но русские превращаются в кракозябры:

```
184113, 745-?·?? ???? 17.07.2012,?°?? '???????????????????? ????????',7826729992,?°?? '???????????????????? ????????',7826729992,?°?????????°????????????????,???°??.?????????????° ???°??. (???? ???????????????? ??????. ???? ???°?????????? ????.),???????°??????.????????????????,-,20120720,20170405,20170601,-,http://www.gati-online.ru/op
```

Решении я нашел, но для [C++](https://nicknixer.ru/programmirovanie/russkie-simvolybukvy-pri-vvodevyvode-v-konsol-na-c/) и [PHP](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/745696/%D0%9D%D0%B5-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B5-%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7-exec). Но вот для Java`ы нет...

Вот код:

```
public class main {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        String pathToFIle = args[0];
        String date = args[1];

        try(FileInputStream fin=new FileInputStream(pathToFIle))  {
            int i=-1;
            while((i=fin.read())!=-1){
                System.out.print((char)i);
            }
        }
        catch(IOException ex){ System.out.println(ex.getMessage()); }

        System.out.println("date = " + date);
    }
}
```

Comment: Посмотрите в какой кодировке находится файл и в какой кодировке вы его считываете.

Comment: @Bakuard Кодировка текстового файла - UTF-8, кодировка с помощью которой я считываю этот текстовый файл тоже UTF-8, пробовал менять кодировки, к примеру Windows-1251, бессмысленно. Не знаю что ещё добавить, кроме ещё литра воды, чтобы -2 не было.

Comment: Отредактируйте ваш вопрос - покажите код с помощью которого вы считываете файл

Comment: @Bakuard я добавил код

Comment: Объект FileInputStream считывает файлы по байтам. Символы кириллицы в UTF-8 кодируются двумя байтами. Для считывания текста лучше использовать объекты типа FileReader.

Comment: @Bakuard прошу прощения, но ничего не работает...

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/111500/discussion-between-bakuard-and-arthur).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(По просьбе в комментариях - я вынес свой комментарий в ответ)
Попробуйте эту конструкцию:

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(file), StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
```

Здесь вы явно задаете кодировку в которой считываете файл (по умолчанию, FileInputStream считывает файлы в системной кодировке). С помощью BufferedReader вы можете считывать файл построчно.